# observeValueForKeyPath on nsoperation queue not get called when operation fisnished

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an `findBusinessOperationQueue`, in order to know how many `nsoperation` remaining on it, I addObserver based on `operations`:

```
- (id)init {
       if (self = [super init]) {
           self.findBusinessOperationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
           [self.getBusinessOperationQueue addObserver:self
                                             forKeyPath:@"operations"
                                               options:0
                                                context:nil];

        }
        return self;
    }
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                              ofObject:(id)object
                                change:(NSDictionary *)change
                               context:(void *)context {
              if ([object isEqual:self.findBusinessOperationQueue] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"])
                NSLog(@"        ======> FindBusinessoperationQueue size: %lu", (unsigned long)[[self.findBusinessOperationQueue operations] count]);

            else
                [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                                     ofObject:object
                                       change:change
                                      context:context];
        }
```

After adding `nsoperations` into it :

```
FindBusinessOperation *op = [[FindBusinessOperation alloc] init];
[self.findBusinessOperationQueue addOperation:op];
```

I am getting what I expect on the console :

```
======> FindBusinessOperationQueue size: 1
```

At FindBusinessOperation, i am using `NSURLSessionDataTask` to download some data from server ( in this case I download the pdf file.

**APPROACH 1** : using NSURLSessionDataTask without completion block

```
-(void)start {
    // Dont do any downloading if op is cancelled
    if (self.cancelled)
        return;

    NSLog(@"                    FindBusiness START :main thread = %d",[NSThread isMainThread]);

    // Change to isExecuting status
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isExecuting", nil)];
    opExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isExecuting", nil)];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449359348_sampler.pdf"]];

    [task resume];
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);

    downloadSize=[response expectedContentLength];
    dataToDownload=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [dataToDownload appendData:data];
    CGFloat dataDownloaded  = [dataToDownload length ]/downloadSize ;
    NSLog(@"----> is %f",dataDownloaded);
    if ( (int)dataDownloaded == 1 )
        [self opCompleted];

}

-(BOOL)isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isOpExecuting {
    return opExecuting;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return opCompleted;
}

-(void)opCompleted {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isExecuting", nil)];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isFinished", nil)];

    opExecuting = NO;
    opCompleted = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isExecuting", nil)];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"isFinished", nil)];
}
```

As we have seen, `opCompleted` will be called when we finish to download all data and it will notify `(BOOL)isFisnied` as well.  Theoretically, this `nsoperation` will be removed away from `findBusinessOperationQueue` and we will expect the remaining operation on the queue is 0.

Unfortunately, `observeValueForKeyPath` is not getting called at the end of process. Still struggling it for now.

**APPROACH 2** using `NSURLSessionDataTask` with completionBlock like below

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449359348_sampler.pdf"]
                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                 NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                                 self.statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
                                                 if (self.statusCode == 200)
                                                         NSLog(@"DONE ");                                                       
                                                     else
                                                         NSLog(@"FAILED ");

                                                     NSLog(@"FINDBUSINESS DONE. S:%.2f MB", (float)data.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);
                                                     [self opCompleted];
                                                     self.resultBlock([summary.business allObjects]);
                                                 }
                                             }
                                  ];


    [task resume];
```

and then it works

```
   2014-10-30 13:53:35.544 Discovery[1994:485268]         ======> FindBusinessoperationQueue size: 1
   2014-10-30 13:53:45.472 Discovery[1994:485268]                     FINDBUSINESS DONE. #:0  S:6.97 M
   2014-10-30 13:53:50.588 Discovery[1994:485268]         ======> FindBusinessoperationQueue size: 0
```

Question:  Why the latter approach does not work ?

If you encounter this problem before, please give me a hint and all answers are welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'll throw my hat in the ring and see if I can help. There is actually a lot going on here, but some things are unclear from your code snippets, since we don't actually have the full picture.

First, you didn't explicitly say it, but is there a reason why you are making FindBusinessOperation concurrent? Operations generally go on an operation queue queue, and queues will always perform their operations on a background thread. You only need to make an operation concurrent if you are observing the operation AND your observer needs to be KVO compliant, reporting state changes to an observer about its queued operations. See [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8) and [KVO Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE)

Second, in your observing class, are you holding a strong reference to the FindBusinessOperation operation? It doesn't seem like you are, and so when the queue dequeues your finished operation, the operation is likely set to nil by the system (and then in turn your queue's operations array may be set to nil). I don't think KVO sends a notification when an observee is set to nil.

You may also consider registering your observer with the keyPath @"operationCount" instead of @"operations", as there may be a problem with to-many relationships in your setup. See [To-Many Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-SW5)

You may also find success in shifting your approach to utilize [NSOperation's setCompletionBlock: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW33). In the completion block, you could check your queue's operationCount - you may need to consider synchronization as well as that block retaining a pointer to your queue instance.
You could also use this completion block to trigger your operation's final KVO notification.

Without the whole source, I'm afraid I can't tell exactly why your first approach fails while your second approach does not.